# I want to write out "NULL" values from 1 column into an excel file from a DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, excel, null, export

I have multiple excel files. I import the data into 1 DataFrame in Python. Then I sort the information by an Index field, and afterwards I want to export the Dataframe into an excel file.
All goes well, but unfortunately in the column "Priority" the cell value is either an integer or the string "NULL", and I want to return these values into the exported file. Unfortunately I receive only the numbers back in the exported file in the "Priority" column. This column can be in different positions in the files.
How can I export into an excel file the Dataframe with "NULL" strings as well as the integers in the "Priority" column?

My working solution is:
dataframe["Priority"].fillna("NULL", inplace = True)

Unfortunately this will be deprecated in a future release, as:
Setting an item of incompatible dtype is deprecated and will raise in a future error of pandas. Value 'NULL' has dtype incompatible with float64, please explicitly cast to a compatible dtype first.

Comment: Is there a valid float64 value you can use to *mean* NULL, which can then be changed to actual NULLs in the spreadsheet?

Comment: As the final spreadsheet is then checked by an automated process I don't have access to I must have "NULL" in those CELLs or the values.
 Currently the only solution I see here, is that I edit the files again without Dataframes and change the empty cells to NULLs, but this would take up a lot of time, as I need to reopen each file again, access each cell to check if it is empty or has an integer value and change them accordingly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution Approach 1:
If you want to keep NULL fields as they are in the DataFrame when writing to an Excel file using to_excel(), you can use the na_rep parameter. The na_rep parameter allows you to specify the representation of NaN values (NULL in the DataFrame) in the output file. It will work on all the NULL values across dataframe

```
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
# Specify na_rep to represent NULL values in the Excel file
output_file = 'output.xlsx'
df.to_excel(output_file, na_rep='NULL', index=False)
```

Solution Approach 2:
The *replace* method is used to replace *pd.NA* (representing NULL values) with the specified null_repalcement_value ('NULL' in your case) only in that column. The rest of the DataFrame remains unchanged.

```
# value by which NaN/NULL going to replace
null_repalcement_value = 'NULL' 

# Update a specific column to replace NaN with NULL
column_to_keep_null = 'Priority'
df[column_to_keep_null] = df[column_to_keep_null].replace({pd.NA: 
null_repalcement_value})

# Write the modified DataFrame to an Excel file
output_file = 'output.xlsx'
df.to_excel(output_file, index=False)
```

Comment: The situation is, that I want to have the exported value be "NULL" in the excel sheet. Currently it return empty cells. 
 I don't want to replace "NULL" with other values
 Or a different question: how can I export the resulting table into an excel file, so that the replacement_value is changed back to the string "NULL"?

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the dtype of the column to strings and use fillna after that.

```
df['Priority'] = df['Priority'].astype('object')
```

Comment: Hi Triky, unfortunately this has the same effect. As it is NULL string value, it becomes a NULL object as well and as such the cell stays empty.